# template repeat in polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I've created a test polymer element where in I was figuring out how to use use arrays in templates. My code does not work and the documentation for 1.0 doesn't really talk much about how to use repeat in template tags.

my element:

```
    <!-- Imports polymer -->
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- Defines element markup -->
<dom-module id="my-element" >
    <template>
    <style>
    my-element
    </style>
    <h2>{{data}}</h2>
    <ul>
    <template repeat={{column in columns}} bind>
    <li>{{column}}</li>
    </template>
    </ul>

    </template>
</dom-module>

<!-- Registers custom element -->
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',

    // Fires when an instance of the element is created
    created: function() {



    },

    // Fires when the local DOM has been fully prepared
    ready: function() {},

    // Fires when the element was inserted into the document
    attached: function() {},

    // Fires when the element was removed from the document
    detached: function() {},

    // Fires when an attribute was added, removed, or updated
    attributeChanged: function(name, type) {

    alert("changed");

    },

    properties:{

    data :String,
    columns:Array

    }
});
</script>
```

and the index.html page where I'm using the element:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>&lt;my-repo&gt;</title>

    <!-- Imports polyfill -->
    <script src="webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Imports
```

custom element -->

```
<link rel="import" href="my-element.html">
```

```
<!-- Runs custom element -->
<my-element users = '{{[1,2,3,4]}}'  data="This is a polymer table"></my-element>
```

Please let me know what's wrong with my code!!

Comment: See the docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat) for how to repeat templates.

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't realize it was "There" hehe

Comment: And just letting you know that it worked in IE ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{users}}">
  <li>{{item}}</li>
</template>
```

And in main file:

```
<my-element users="[1,2,3,4]" data="This is a polymer table"></my-element>
```

You can search Youtube for Polycast, a series by Google Developers where they're talking about Polymer for beginners and showing cool tricks.

Answer (score 0):

[Polymer 1.0 does not allow expressions](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#data-binding) in data binding. The problem is in:

```
<my-element users = '{{[1,2,3,4]}}' ...>
```

You need to replace `{{[1,2,3,4]}}` with a property. Something like this:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <my-element users = '{{myarray}}'  data="This is a polymer table"></my-element>
</template>
<script>
(function() {
  var template = document.querySelector('template[is="dom-bind"]');
  template.myarray = [1,2,3,4]; 
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Not true. It is possible to set an array/object property declaratively. Just drop the binding syntax:  `<my-element users='[1,2,3,4]'>`